# Embedded Service Live Chat : HTMLEncoded Chat Text on Client

Tags: service, chat, embedded

We have implemented the Embedded Service Live Chat. into a .NET MVC application using the Snap-In javascript.

When the client receives a response with various special characters (apostrophes, less than signs. etc); The client actually gets the response in HTML Encoded Characters.
Example:     **"I'm here"**  becomes **i'm here**

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: SS]

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of component you have that's sending your live chat feed from your web site. We don't know if you have an Aura Component on the web site or some other kind of standard web application page. That said, it appears to me the component on the web site end is HTML encoding special characters before it sends it to your .NET Application. If it is, either you need to decode it before you display it, or change what it does before it sends it to your .NET App.